# How to display element from an array with loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an array that contains 7 objects which are questions as follows:

```
var questions = [ {question: 'Which turkish club did former Leeds player Harry Kewell join in 2008, which caused an uproar amongst Leeds supporters?'}, 
            {question: 'Who is the former Liverpool star who beat Ruud Van Nistelrooy\'s record of most prolific foreign goalscorer in their debut in the Premier League?'},
             {question: 'Who scored Liverpool\'s winner in \'that\' first 4-3 game against Kevin Keegan\'s Newcastle United in April 1996?'},
             {question: 'Which club was former Leeds Unted player Eric Cantona sold to in 1992?'},
             {question: 'Which former Aston Villa and Ireland midfielder went on to become a regular TV pundit with ITV?'},
             {question: 'How many European Cups had Liverpool won up to and including 2007-8?'},
             {question: 'Name the Liverpool scorers for the \'miracle of Istanbul\'.'}
];
```

I would like to display each question using a loop when a button is clicked through the alert function. I need to just display the question that's already in the array. I don't want to ask the user for anything. So when the button is clicked I just want to pull out the first element and display that using alert(), then when the button is clicked again I want to display the second element until all of the elements have been displayed via clicking the button.

As an example I have tried to use the onlick property of the button along with a for loop to try and get the question to display as follows here on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvkvjas/):

but the this displays all of the questions in the array with one click.

Thanks

Comment: A “not sure” in programming can be easily redeemed with trying and experimenting.

Comment: You don't need to use a loop. You juste have to call questions[i] where i is the number of times the person clicked on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this. All you need is a variable that keeps track of how many times the button has been clicked (or a magic one-liner like the answer provided by @naomik).

```
var timesClicked = 0;
```

In your `onClick()` method:

```
var answer = prompt(questions[timesClicked]);  // ask user a question, store the answer
if(timesClicked < questions.length)
    timesClicked++;
else  // optionally you can reset the counter after all the questions have been answered
    timesClicked = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not exactly what you want, but here's a start

```
var answers = questions.map(function(q) { return prompt(q.question); });
```

After all of the questions have been answered, you can see the answers

```
console.log(answers);
```

Comment: Wow, that’s a beautiful way of using `map` and `prompt`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do that is to use a counter:

```
var questions = ....
var counter = 0;
function onButtonClick(){
    alert(questions[counter]['question']);
}
```

You could simplify things by just using an array of strings instead of an array of objects containing strings.

```
var questions = ['question1', 'question2'...];
var counter = 0;
function onButtonClick(){
    alert(questions[counter]);
}
```

You can use the prompt command if you want the user to give you answers:

```
var questions = ['question1', 'question2'...];
var answers = new Array();
var counter = 0;
function onButtonClick(){
    answers.push(prompt(questions[counter++]['question']));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjvkvjas/2/).

You could experiment with something like

```
const answers = [];

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(questions.length){
    answers.push(prompt(questions.pop().question));
  }
});
```

It’s a compact solution without any counting variables. Instead of `pop`, `shift` is also possible.